# Issue Connecting ClientWebSocket in Unity Through a Proxy (Android and IOS)

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, http-proxy

I'm attempting to connect to a WebSocket server using `ClientWebSocket` in Unity with a proxy configuration. Here's my code snippet:

```cs
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;

var socket = new ClientWebSocket();
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, false); // I tried to set the DefaultWebProxy too, but I get the same error 
socket.Options.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, false);
                
await socket.ConnectAsync(uri, token);
```

But it's giving me a 'Unable to connect to the remote server' error. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): !!! System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): mono-io-layer-error (111)
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__10_0 (System.IAsyncResult iar) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<>c.<Complete>b__27_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
11-10 14:16:41.013 I/Unity (12692): at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallb
```

---

I successfully made an HTTP request using `HttpWebRequest` with proxy configuration. The code looks like this:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, false);
request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, false);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

---

I also tried to implement `IWebProxy` like this:

```
public class WebSocketProxy : IWebProxy
{
    private ICredentials iCredentials;
    private Uri webProxyUri;

    public WebSocketProxy(Uri proxyUri)
    {
        webProxyUri = proxyUri;
    }

    public ICredentials Credentials
    {
        get
        {
            return iCredentials;
        }
        set
        {
            if (iCredentials != value)
            {
                iCredentials = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri? GetProxy(Uri destUri)
    {
        // Always use the same proxy.
        Debug.Log("GetProxy called");
        return webProxyUri;
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri hostUri)
    {
        // Never bypass the proxy.
        Debug.Log("IsBypassed called");
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, based on the logs, it appears that the `GetProxy` and `IsBypassed` methods are never being called.

Comment: i dont see you calling either

Comment: I've set up my implementation as `socket.Options.Proxy = new WebSocketProxy(new Uri(proxyUrl))`, and my expectation was that the `ClientWebSocket` class would automatically call the methods from the `WebSocketProxy`. However, it appears that these methods (`GetProxy` and `IsBypassed`) are not being invoked as expected.

Comment: the docs do not suggest that either is called automatically

Comment: So, I believed that setting the `Proxy` property of the `ClientWebSocket` would set an `IWebProxy` that the `ClientWebSocket` class would utilize. My expectation was that the `WebRequest` class would then call the methods provided by the `IWebProxy` to handle requests made through the `ClientWebSocket` class.  But, am I mistaken here?